# C++ return by rvalue reference

Tags: c++, value-categories

```
template<typename T>
class Stack {
    private:
        std::vector<T> elems;  
    public:
        Stack () = default;
        Stack (T const& elem)
          : elems({elem}) {}
};

template<typename T>
Stack<T>&& dummy(Stack<T>&& a){
    return std::move(a);
}

int main(){
    Stack<int> first_a = 10;
    Stack<int> second_a = dummy(std::move(first_a));
    ...
}
```

The `dummy` function has a right value reference return type `Stack<T>&&`. However `second_a` has a `Stack<int>` type. My questions follow:

- How can the return value of the dummy function, which has type `Stack<T>&&` be passed to a
  different type `Stack<int> second_a`? How does it work? Is there a implicit conversion?

Comment: They don't seem to have different types though. The template parameter is I would guess was automatically deduced as `T = int` making the return type `Stack<int>&&`. You could even confirm this with a debugger/looking at demangled generated assembly

Comment: The return type of dummy function is Stack<int>&&, which is an rvalue reference type, however, Stack<int> is not a reference type? Could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: `second_a` is initialized with the `dummy(std::move(first_a))` expression. This expression has category _rvalue_ and it refers to the `first_a` object (of type `Stack<int>`). Consequently, since there is no move constructor in `Stack`, `second_a` is initialized with copy construtor (constant lvalue reference can bound rvalue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does it work?

`second_a` is copy initialised from the return value.

> Is there a implicit conversion?

Yes. The rvalue reference to non-const is implicity converted into the lvalue reference to const that is the parameter of the copy constructor.

`dummy` is quite pointless function. It's just `std::move` that can be called only on a `Stack`. `std::move` itself is also a function that returns an rvalue reference. The following is effectively the same:

```
Stack<int> second_a = std::move(first_a);
```

And since the class template doesn't have a move constructor, it's effectively same as:

```
Stack<int> second_a = first_a;
```

Comment: If Stack has a move contructor, there will be no implicit conversion since `second_a` will be initialized using move ctor.  The implicit conversion exists only when move ctor is missing in this case. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Willi If the type of the parameter matches the argument, then there is no conversion (unless you count "identity conversion" as a conversion).

Comment: @eeorika Won't `Stack` have the copy constructor, copy assignment, move constructor, move assignment and destructor automatically generated by the compiler?

Comment: @rturrado No, if you have a user declared copy constructor, then a move constructor won't be implicitly declared.

Comment: @eeorika Oh, sorry! I had misread it as a default constructor and a user-defined constructor. Thanks!